# Is there an Excel function to look up & not stop at first match but look for all the values (dates) and return "Yes/No" if it matches certain date

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

I have two data sets in excel. Like below (Table 1 and Table 2) I am trying to get result in Table 1 as Yes/No if the date matches for the corresponding ID in Table 2. See result Column in Table 1. Can you please let me know how this can be achieved using excel formulas? Thanks

Table 1

[image]
[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGwzl.png)

Table 2

[image]
[Table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmhVk.png)

Comment: Right now using basic excel (vlookup etc).  Is this more easily achievable in python or VBA?

Comment: If you just want an exact match on row and column do `=(Sheet1!A2=Sheet2!A2)*(Sheet1!B2=Sheet2!B2)`

Comment: We are all happy to help, but still have to follow some rules to keep it clean. This question is more suitable for superuser.com   Please read the guide for asking in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($I$2:$I$5=$A2)*($J$2:$J$5=$B2))>0,"Yes","No")` where I2:J5 is your Table2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. use COUNTIFS. Count if any row in table 2 holds same id and date that the one you got in each row of table 1. If the count returns 0, means *no*. If the count is not zero, it means *yes*. You could customize the result with an IF combined with COUNTIFS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

[image]

The formula I've used is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($G$3:$G$6;A3;$H$3:$H$6;B3)=0;"No";"Yes")
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the support,.